# java.lang.IllegalStateException: getReader() has already been called for this request

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I want to add logging to my Servlet, so I've created Filter which should display request and go to the Servlet. But unfortunately I've encoutered exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getReader() has already been called for this request
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getInputStream(Request.java:948)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getInputStream(RequestFacade.java:338)
    at com.noelios.restlet.ext.servlet.ServletCall.getRequestEntityStream(ServletCall.java:190)
```

So to fix this problem I've found solution with Wrapper, but it doesn't work. What else can I use/change in code? Any ideas?

[MyHttpServletRequestWrapper]

```
public class MyHttpServletRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper
{
    public MyHttpServletRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        super(request);
    }

    private String getBodyAsString()
    {
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
        buff.append(" BODY_DATA START [ ");
        char[] charArr = new char[getContentLength()];
        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(getReader());
            reader.read(charArr, 0, charArr.length);
            reader.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        buff.append(charArr);
        buff.append(" ] BODY_DATA END ");
        return buff.toString();
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return getBodyAsString();
    }
}
```

[MyFilter]

```
public class MyFilterimplements Filter
{
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        final HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        final HttpServletRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new MyHttpServletRequestWrapper(httpServletRequest);
        final String requestBody = requestWrapper.toString();

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Looks like the restlet framework has called `getRequestEntityStream()` on the Request object which in turn calls `getInputStream()`, so calling `getReader()` on the request throws `IllegalStateException`. The Servlet API documentation for `getReader()` and `getInputStream()` says:

```
 public java.io.BufferedReader getReader()
    ...
    ...
Throws:
    java.lang.IllegalStateException - if getInputStream() method has been called on this request

 public ServletInputStream getInputStream()
    ...
    ...
    Throws:
    java.lang.IllegalStateException - if the getReader() method has already been called for this request
```

From the documentation, it seems that we cannot call both `getReader()` and `getInputStream()` on the Request object. I suggest you use `getInputStream()` rather than `getReader()` in your wrapper.

Answer (score 18):

Use `ContentCachingRequestWrapper` class. Wrapping `HttpServletRequest` in this will resolve the issue.

**Sample** : if you want to convert your **"HttpServletRequest servletRequest"** you can do some thing like

```
import org.springframework.web.util.ContentCachingRequestWrapper;

ContentCachingRequestWrapper request = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(servletRequest);
```

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 8):

As far as I can tell servlets are fundamentally broken in this regard.  You can try and work around this problem as outlined [here](http://natch3z.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/read-request-body-in-filter.html) but that causes other mysterious problems when other things try and work with it.

Effectively he suggests cloning the request, reading the body and then in the the cloned class overriding the getReader and getInputStream methods to return the stuff already retrieved.

The code I ended up with was this:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletInputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;
import java.io.*;

//this class stops reading the request payload twice causing an exception
public class WrappedRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper
{
    private String _body;
    private HttpServletRequest _request;

    public WrappedRequest(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException
    {
        super(request);
        _request = request;

        _body = "";
        try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = request.getReader())
        {
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                _body += line;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException
    {
        final ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(_body.getBytes());
        return new ServletInputStream()
        {
            public int read() throws IOException
            {
                return byteArrayInputStream.read();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException
    {
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getInputStream()));
    }
}
```

Anyway this appeared to be working fine until we realised that uploading a file from the browser wasn't working.  I bisected through the changes and discovered this was the culprit.

Some people in the comments in that article say you need to override methods to do with parameters but don't explain how to do this.

As a result I checked to see if there was any difference in the two requests.  However after cloning the request it had identical sets of parameters (both original request + cloned had none) aswell as an identical set of headers.

However in some manner the request was being effected and screwing up the understanding of the request further down the line - in my case causing a bizaare error in a library (extdirectspring) where something was trying to read the contents as Json.  Taking out the code that read the body in the filter made it work again.

My calling code looked like this:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException
{
    HttpServletRequest properRequest = ((HttpServletRequest)request);

    String pathInfo = properRequest.getPathInfo();
    String target = "";
    if(pathInfo == null)
        pathInfo = "";

    if(pathInfo.equals("/router"))
    {
        //note this is because servlet requests hate you!
        //if you read their contents more than once then they throw an exception so we need to do some madness
        //to make this not the case
        WrappedRequest wrappedRequest = new WrappedRequest(properRequest);
        target = ParseExtDirectTargetFrom(wrappedRequest);
        request = wrappedRequest;
    }

    boolean callingSpecialResetMethod = pathInfo.equals("/resetErrorState") || target.equals("resetErrorState");
    if(_errorHandler.IsRejectingRequests() && !callingSpecialResetMethod)
        return;

    try {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    catch (Exception exception) {
        ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "ERROR");
        _errorHandler.NotifyOf(exception);
    }
}
```

I've ommitted the contents of `ParseExtDirectTargetFrom` but it calls getReader().

In my case the filter was working for all other requests but the strange behaviour in this case made me realise something wasn't quite right and what I was trying to do (implement sensible exception handling behaviour for tests) wasn't worth potentially breaking random future requests (as I couldn't figure out what had caused the request to become broken).

Also it's worth noting that the broken code is unavoidable - I assumed it might be something from spring but ServletRequest goes all the way up - thats all you get even if you were making a servlet from scratch by subclassing [HttpServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html)

My recommendation would be this - **don't read the request body in a filter**.  You'll be opening up a can of worms that will cause strange problems later on.

Comment: You can use `shouldNotFilter` if your filter class extends `OncePerRequestFilter` then read the request uri to determine if it follows a pattern to use the filter.

Answer (score 6):

The main problem is that you can't read the input both as binary stream and character stream, not even if the one is called in a filter and the other in the servlet.

Answer (score 3):

Implementing other solutions would possibly lead you to the following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getInputStream() has already been called for this request
```

To read HttpServletRequest, following needs to be implemented.

**Background:**

To get the request body from the request, HttpServletRequest is provided with and InputStream class. The getReader() is what is usually used to stream the request. This function internally calls getInputStream() function, which returns us the stream for us to read the request. Now, note that its a stream, and can be opened only once. Hence, while reading this (i.e. implementing the solutions given in this thread) it usually throws "stream is already closed." exception. Now this happens because, the tomcat server has already opened and read the request once. Hence, we need to implement a wrapper here, which helps us to re-open an already read stream by keeping an instance of it. This wrapper again, cannot be used directly, instead, needs to be added at spring filter level, while the tomcat server is reading it.

**Code:**

Servlet Request Wrapper Class:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import javax.servlet.ReadListener;
import javax.servlet.ServletInputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;
import java.io.*;
@Slf4j
public class MyHttpServletRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
private final String body;public MyHttpServletRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
    super(request);

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();

        if (inputStream != null) {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            char[] charBuffer = new char[128];
            int bytesRead = -1;

            while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) > 0) {
                stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        } else {
            stringBuilder.append("");
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        log.error("Error reading the request body...");
    } finally {
        if (bufferedReader != null) {
            try {
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                log.error("Error closing bufferedReader...");
            }
        }
    }

    body = stringBuilder.toString();
}

@Override
public ServletInputStream getInputStream () {
    final ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(body.getBytes());

    ServletInputStream inputStream = new ServletInputStream() {
        @Override
        public boolean isFinished() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isReady() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void setReadListener(ReadListener readListener) {

        }

        public int read () throws IOException {
            return byteArrayInputStream.read();
        }
    };

    return inputStream;
}

@Override
public BufferedReader getReader(){
    return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getInputStream()));
}
}
```

Now we need to use the wrapper my implementing it in a filter, as shown below.

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Objects;
@Component
@Order(1)
@Slf4j
public class ServletFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        ServletRequest requestWrapper = null;
        if (servletRequest instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            requestWrapper = new MyHttpServletRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest);
        }
        if (Objects.isNull(requestWrapper)){
            filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        } else {
            filterChain.doFilter(requestWrapper, servletResponse);
        }
}
}
```

Then, the suggested implementations can be used as follows to get the request body as following:

```
    private String getRequestBody(HttpServletRequest request) {
    try {
        return request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "{}";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe this is something quite obvious, but I want to share with you this code that works OK for me. In a Spring Boot project with JWT, for the request of the client, was necessary to save all requests with their responses in a database table, and the same time authorize the access to consume the resources. Of course, I used `getReader()` for getting the  request body, but I was obtaining java.lang.IllegalStateException...

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomAuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

private final AuthorizationService authorizationService;
private String requestBody;     

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) {
    HttpRequestDto requestDto = new HttpRequestDto();
    try {
        if (RequestMethod.POST.name().equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod()) && requestBody != null) { //This line and validation is useful for me [requestBody != null]
            requestBody = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
        }
        //Do all JWT control
        requestDto.setRequestURI(request.getRequestURI());
        requestDto.setMethod(request.getMethod());
        requestDto.setBody(requestBody);
    }catch (IOException ie) {
        responseError(_3001, response, ie);
    } finally {
        try {
            ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);
            filterChain.doFilter(request, responseWrapper);
            saveResponse(responseWrapper, requestDto);
        } catch (ServletException | IOException se) {
            responseError(_3002, response, se);
        }
    }
}


private void saveResponse(ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper, HttpRequestDto requestDto) {
    try {
        HttpResponseDto responseDto = new HttpResponseDto();
        responseDto.setStatus(responseWrapper.getStatus());
        byte[] responseArray = responseWrapper.getContentAsByteArray();
        String responseBody = new String(responseArray, responseWrapper.getCharacterEncoding());
        responseDto.setBody(responseBody);
        responseWrapper.copyBodyToResponse();
        authorizationService.seveInDatabase(requestDto, responseDto);            
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error ServletException | IOException in CustomAuthorizationFilter.saveResponse", e);
    }
}

private void responseError(LogCode code, HttpServletResponse response, Exception e) {
    try {
        Map<String, Object> error = new HashMap<>();
        error.put("log", LogUtil.getLog(code));
        error.put("message", e.getMessage());
        response.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        new ObjectMapper().writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), error);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ie) {
        log.error("Error IOException in HttpLoggingFilter.responseError:", ie);
    }
}


public String getRequestBody() {
    return requestBody;
}

public void setRequestBody(String requestBody) {
    this.requestBody = requestBody;
}

}
```

So my solution was use getter and setter methods of de local attribute requestBody, for validate if this is or not null and does not call again getReader() method because save in memory when set value. This worked perfect for me. Regards.