# While retiring requested payload form HttpServeletRequest throwing Java Lang Illegal State Exception

Tags: java, servlets

trying to retrieve that data for HttpServeletRequest object. But it throwing Java Lang Illegal State Exception:

> getInputStream() has already been called for this request

```
try {
        String test = null;
        if (request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            test = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
        }
    } catch (Exception ec) {
        logger.error("Exception newRemarksUpdated : " + ec.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: you can only read this data once https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getReader--

Comment: ok . I used getInputStream() then also it is throwing error "getInputStream()has already been called for this request"

Answer (score 0):

First, you are comparing object instance with itself. The condition for this if statement will always be true.

```
if (request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod()))
```

Second, create an instance of your reader, so it will be easier to manipulate.

```
BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
String collected = reader.lines()
        .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
```

Third, it seems like you are calling `getInputStream()` method twice, which cannot be done. You can read more about it in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7318845/6252399) post.

Answer (score 0):

According the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getReader) you're not able to use both character-oriented and byte-oriented streams to read a request. I bet you called `getInputStream()` somewhere else. You should use similar approach everywhere.