# XtextServices Servlet returns CORS-Error with HTTP-Code 404 but not other REST-Controllers

Tags: spring, vue.js, servlets, cors, xtext

I currently try to set up a Xtext web editor with "[Context Mapper](https://contextmapper.org/docs/getting-started/)" as DSL.

The backend is a basic Spring Boot backend with the [Context Mapper DSL](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.contextmapper/context-mapper-dsl) and [Context Mapper LSP](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.contextmapper/context-mapper-lsp) (Language Server).

The frontend is a VueJS frontend made with the help of this [guide](https://nicogreve.de/xtext-on-the-web-part-1/). It utilizes everything Eclipse Xtext generates and ports it to a VueJS website.

My only issue now is that the "/xtext-service/*" API return CORS errors with HTTP code 404 while the console of the backend prints absolutely nothing.

The Servlet looks like every other XtextServlet:

```java
@WebServlet(name = "XtextServices", urlPatterns = "/xtext-service/*")
@SuppressWarnings("all")
public class ContextMappingDSLServlet extends XtextServlet {
    private DisposableRegistry disposableRegistry;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        try {
            super.init();
            final Injector injector = new ContextMappingDSLWebSetup().createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration();
            this.disposableRegistry = injector.<DisposableRegistry>getInstance(DisposableRegistry.class);
        } catch (Throwable _e) {
            throw Exceptions.sneakyThrow(_e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        if ((this.disposableRegistry != null)) {
            this.disposableRegistry.dispose();
            this.disposableRegistry = null;
        }
        super.destroy();
    }
}
```

The requests are also the standard requests the Xtext generated web editor invokes and the occurrences request goes through it seems:

```
Response: 
HTTP/1.1 404
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8081
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 21 Oct 2022 16:03:19 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Connection: keep-alive

Request: 
GET /xtext-service/occurrences?resource=1e26589b.cml&caretOffset=1 HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,de;q=0.8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: JSESSIONID=CDE6CC29EE123451F3DF3FF174337EE3
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:8081
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost:8081/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="106", "Google Chrome";v="106", "Not;A=Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
```

The requests to http://localhost:8080/xtext-service/occurrences?resource=1e26589b.cml&caretOffset=1 returns 404 while update throws

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/xtext-service/update?resource=1e26589b.cml' from origin 'http://localhost:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

CORS however is enabled:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods(CorsConfiguration.ALL)
                .allowedHeaders(CorsConfiguration.ALL)
                .allowedOriginPatterns(CorsConfiguration.ALL)
                .allowCredentials(true);
    }
}
```

The non-servlet APIs do work without any issues, but the Xtext-service servlet doesn't, and I don't know why.
@ServletComponentScan is enabled.

Comment: did you try to avoid the problem all together by just having 1 app with multiple servlets https://stackoverflow.com/a/20939923/935687

Comment: (that should already work with ServletComponentScan in embedded spring boot mode

Comment: @ChristianDietrich I didn't do that so far, but that would have been my next idea. I'll try that tomorrow or maybe sunday. Is there still an approach to having them separated or is it generally considered bad practice? I'm still learning about servlets. Never used them consciously.

Comment: no, just an idea. have no idea why the spring cors config does not work for you.

Comment: @ChristianDietrich It seems to work for the /xtext-service/occurrences API as seen above. He probably throws 404 because it doesn't work for the /xtext-service/update one. But I have no idea why those two behave completely different. When reloading the VueJS site, the request won't even remotely go through and return provisional headers

Comment: i would propose you first get the pure xtext variant running without vue. just let spring serve the static html from the webapp folder in mydsl.web (i had to change MyDslServlet to use ContentCachingRequestWrapper and then it worked perfectly fine. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44881961/935687). now the default editor sends update and other services

Comment: i assume if you serve on the same port, then both willl also work with vue